# Return mysql data exhausted from php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a module where users can interact with some filters, specially by range date. There are some managers who needs to export data from last 3 months from my website (php and mysql), but everything works ok when they filter by some days but the whole month and even more than 2 months, php never returns result.
I have noticed that my query ie

```
mysql_query("SELECT * from query where date_f between '2015-05-01' and '2015-07-30'"); //WHERE * can be 12 columns
```

then i loop using "while" to draw my table, ie

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){...some code to draw tr's}.
```

This way i just draw to my users 500rows (on the website under a condition),then the next ones i let them use an url to export the whole data using the same focus, but seems somethings wrong. I have activated my display_erros but i dont get any info, i just get something like exhausted. Php and mysql driver seems to do not handle big data. I have incremented my memory size by `ini_set('memory_limit','500M');` and yes it helps but im not sure that i have to do that for just a query?. There must be another way to solve this problem or another focus.
to export my data i use

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel; name=excel");  
header("Content-Disposition: filename=ficheroExcel.xls");  
header("Pragma: no-cache");  
header("Expires: 1");  
mysql_query("SELECT * from query where date_f between '2015-05-01' and '2015-07-30'"); //WHERE * can be 12 columns  
$html=NULL;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){    
$html.="<tr>";    
$html.="<td>".$row["col1"]."</td>";
$html.="<td>".$row["col2"]."</td>";
..
$html.="</tr>";  
}
```

here i run my code function to draw the results and export info user needs

I have also tried with php library to export but they handle arrays and filling big data on array is not ideal.

Comment: show actual code, not fakeish pseudocode. "code to draw trs" could be ANYTHING. if one of those cells is a blob, and you're building into a string, then yeah, you'll run out of memory.

Comment: Joe, i have made some modifications to my query. I just dont know how to make some format here in stackoverflow im very new here. For that reason i've omited so manythings. Seems stackoverflow's manager has edited my initial question because it didnt look so cool as it looks now. Nevertheless, i hope with this upgrade you could undertand my problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow user2570870. There is an awful lot wrong with your question and you've failed to address the key point made by Marc B. Please go read some of the *many* other posts about slow response/performance in PHP and particularly mysql to see what you should be looking at and including in your question if you are still unable to solve it yourself.

Comment: My problem is not a slow response, my problem is that php doesnt response when i make a mysql_result for big data.